# Vaildation fails when using pagenation in datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I have integrated the data table with 10 records per page .Here some of the fields are as text fields that is my data is like

testtest1text filed content

The submit button is displayed below the data table.While submitting the form i put validation for text filed.The validation is working fine for the first pge .If i  navigate the second page .The validation.The validation used this

```
function validatereaddsalary() { 
     var totrows = document.getElementById('txxinc').value;
     for(var i=1;i<=totrows;i++) { 
         var chknag=document.getElementById('idTextField'+i).value;
         if(document.getElementById('idTextField'+i).value == "") { 
            document.getElementById('sal_err'+i).innerHTML = 'Please Enter Salary';
            document.getElementById('sal_err'+i).style.display='block'; 
            document.getElementById('idTextField'+i).focus(); return false;
         }
      }
 }
```

hope that the navigate page data is dynamically loaded .so i affect the validation script.How to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this wiki can help you

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/edatatables/
```